# how to get default Android trust store

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, truststore

On Android, I need to validate if the certificate presented by the server is in the CRL. To do so, I found in another answer, this would be a way to do it:

```
public static TrustManager[] getCATrustManager(KeyStore trustStore) {
    CertPathBuilder cpb = CertPathBuilder.getInstance("PKIX");
    PKIXRevocationChecker rc = (PKIXRevocationChecker)cpb.getRevocationChecker();
    rc.setOptions(EnumSet.of(
            PKIXRevocationChecker.Option.PREFER_CRLS, // prefer CLR over OCSP
            PKIXRevocationChecker.Option.ONLY_END_ENTITY,
            PKIXRevocationChecker.Option.NO_FALLBACK)); // don't fall back to OCSP checking

    PKIXBuilderParameters pkixParams = new PKIXBuilderParameters(trustStore, new X509CertSelector());
    pkixParams.addCertPathChecker(rc);

    TrustManagerFactory tmFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmFactory.init(new CertPathTrustManagerParameters(pkixParams));
    ...
}
```

My question is, **how to get the default Android trust store**? I've checked my phone and there are lots of CA already installed, but I can't figure out a way to get it programatically. So far all I saw is how to get one created by yourself, but not the default one by Android.